# Chinese postman problem

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

Is there any way to modify the Traveling Sales Person algorithm in pgrouting to Route inspection problem (Chinese postman problem)?
I need Route inspection problem and it seems that pgrouting does not support it.

Comment: possible update here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/305218/how-to-build-a-route-that-traverses-every-edge-at-least-once-and-begins-and-ends