# How to build a route that traverses every edge at least once and begins and ends at the same location?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, graph

I have a collection of lines in PostgreSQL w/PostGIS/pgRouting and have built  topology.

I need to produce a route that starts and ends at the same location, but traverses all of the edges.

Can [pgRouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/latest/en/index.html) solve this routing problem? And if so, what approach or routing function(s) should be used?

[image]

Comment: ...or *Chinese Postman Problem*, i.e a *Route Inspection Problem*. and AFAIK not implemented in pgRouting as of yet...it's one hell of a computational effort, especially if the Eulerian circuit is not given.

Comment: Chinese Postman has been implented this year as a Google Summer of Code project named as `ChPP`: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/GSoC-2018-Minimum-cost-flow-and-ChPP We appreciate, if someone could give it a try with a real use case, and if you run into troubles, feel free to talk to us on Gitter or file an issue on Github.

Comment: Documentation is available in the experimental functions section of the development branch: https://docs.pgrouting.org/dev/en/chinesePostmanProblem-family.html

Comment: @ThingumaBob  and FSimardGIS, if you don't know, why do you give a comment, that is actually not correct?

Comment: I figured it was some sort of variant of the CPP--just wasn't sure about the same stop/start location. But I guess that makes sense now that I think about it. Thanks @dkastl, I'll check it out!

Comment: I don't think, that's the case. You can find various combinations of Windows builds here: https://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/ But I couldn't find a development branch build. You could try to run it in Docker: https://github.com/pgRouting/docker-pgrouting But I'm not a Windows user and can't tell, if there are ore obstacles.

Comment: Thanks @dkastl.  I checked winnie first but didn't see it.  I'll see what I can manage w/  docker.

Comment: @dkastl awesome, read the wiki, a brilliant piece of work! I was looking forward to see that function family. I'd be happy to run some scaled test. ...now, why do you let yourself accuse me? don't. not for excluding the latest dev branch commits from 'as of yet'.

Comment: I was able to load the docker image and successfully run the cpp function.  It seems to work. But in my case...I don't need to go  out and back for each edge unless it is necessary.  But the cpp function does this for every edge...which I guess is what a postman does. But not what I need--very close though.